# Wpf Enabling Transparency Throws Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

My WPF App was working well. I then changed background colors for a button, which lies inside a transparent window, saved and compiled/run. Ever since, running my program throws

> Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

with additional info

> System.Windows.UI.Visibility threw an exception

I was unable to undo changes, and now I cannot solve this,unless I remove the "AllowTransparency = True" line. I need the window to be transparent, how can I fix this?

Here's the code for the troublesome block.

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPF.OverlayButtonField"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="OverlayButtonField"
    Width="175"
    Height="139"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    ShowActivated="False"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    Topmost="True"
    Visibility="Visible"
    WindowStyle="None">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You neglected to mention the `InnerException`, which clarifies the problem:

> InvalidOperationException: WindowStyle.None is the only valid value for WindowStyle when AllowsTransparency is true.

The problem is that you're touching `Visibility` before setting `WindowStyle` to `None`. In principle, the order of attributes in XML doesn't matter. In XAML, in practice, it may sometimes matter. This is a case where it does.

Put `Visibility="Visible"` after `WindowStyle="None"`, or put `AllowsTransparency="True"` after both of them -- or better yet, omit `Visibility="Visible"` entirely. It's redundant. `Visible` is the default.

Comment: The editor seems to order attributes on its own, so I was unable to reorder, but omitting Visibility solved the issue. In fact, it seems to have added the attribute on its own. Either way, thank you.